# Reading a file into a C program

Tags: c, struct

The program I have reads the file, displays it accordingly, but then when trying to view the contents again, they are gone.

Structure:

```
typedef struct friends_contact {
    char *First_Name;
    char *Last_Name;
    char *home;
    char *cell;
} fr;
```

Main:

```
int main() {
    fr friends[5];
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    int counter = 0;
    int i = 0;

    menu(friends, &counter, i, buffer);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

If statement in the menu function used to open up the file:

```
if (user_entry1 == 1) {
  printf("Please enter a file name");
  scanf("%s", user_entry3); 

  read = fopen(user_entry3, "r");
}
```

If statement that allows the user to choose to look at the contacts of the address book.

```
if (user_entry == 4 ) {
  print_contact(friends, counter, i, user_entry3);
  if (user_entry1 == 1) {
    file2(friends, counter, i, buffer, read);
  }
}
```

Read function:

```
char file2(fr *friends, int *counter, int i, char buffer[], FILE *read) {
  while (fscanf(read, "%s", buffer) != EOF) {
    friends[i].First_Name = malloc(BUFFSIZE * strlen(buffer));
    strcpy(friends[i].First_Name, buffer);
    return printf("\n""%s ", friends[i].First_Name);       
  }  
  fclose(read);
}
```

If you need me to provide any more code. I'm trying to get it to read the content from the file into the contacts list so I can view, search, or delete them.

P.S. I understand some of the other code may not be perfect, but right now I'm just concerned about figuring this out :).

Comment: messy style obfuscates code meaning.  Please try to keep your style consistent, if nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset your file pointer using `fseek` to the beginning of the file again. Your read function should start like:

```
fseek(read, 0, SEEK_SET); // set file pointer to the beginning of the file
```

Comment: Oh wow, I did now know that. Fixed that issue. Any other magic tricks that will solve my issues for deleting content from the file and searching content from the file? lol

Comment: Nope, those two you'll have to do yourself.  You might be able to use `fgetc` in a loop and search for data that way, but there is not to my knowledge a library function that does that for you.

Comment: Also, just encountered a weird error. If you add a name to the contact list via the program and not the file, it will bring it up on the contact list but then the second time you go to view it, it replaces the first name of the new added contact with the last line from the file. Ex. if `mike smith` is the first contact and the last contact's cell number is 10, then the next time you view the contacts list `mike smith` is replaced with `cell 10 smith`

Comment: @user1781966: this is more like a website to ask individual questions rather than a discussion forum. If you have further problems feel free to create new questions for them too :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to clog up the stack exchange with my random question. Figured people would get upset with my Noobness. I'll start a new one for the next question.

Comment: @user1781966: Don't worry about it. Noobs are great low hanging fruits for rep points here :)

Answer (score 2):

The `file2` function reads each line of the file into `friends[i]` but never increments `i`.  So each new record would overwrite the previous one ... except that the function returns during the first iteration of the loop.  Better to use `if` than `while` in this case.

Other suggestions:

Instead of using `}else;` you can just close the `if` block with `}`.  An `if` needn't be followed by `else`.

Instead of the idiom

```
if (foo == 1) {
  // do stuff
} else if (foo == 2) {
  // do other stuff
} else {
  // do default stuff
}
```

you can use

```
switch (foo)  {
case 1:
  // do stuff
  break;
case 2:
  // do other stuff
  break;
default:
  // do default stuff
}
```

Instead of

```
printf("\n""%s ",friends[i].First_Name);
```

it's more common to use a single string, with the newline at the end:

```
printf("%s\n", friends[i].First_Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't forget to test if the file could be opened or not:

```
if ( user_entry1==1 ){

    printf( "Please enter a file name" );
    scanf( "%s", user_entry3 ); 

    if ( ( read = fopen( user_entry3, "r" ) ) != NULL ){
        printf( "The file couldn't be opened" );
    }
    else{
       .
       .
       .
    }
}
```